# Using flat column or relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value, nosql

I am designing a reward system for my game. I have a table called VirtualItem (VI) (key, display_name), the data contained could be (gd, gold), (dm,diomond). Then I have a Reward table (id, reward_items,etc)

Currently reward_items are a json array of VIs: [[{key: dm, count:5},{key:gd, count10]].There is a web portal allowing user to CRUD reward_items.

My question is, should I use the current flat structure, or add another layer in between and use reference in reward_items instead? Something like reward_items: set_id(referring VirtualItemSet table).

Apparently, using flat structure(json array) will make the query easy. But I probably also need to put dislay_name inside the JSON as well. In addition, when VI changes, its hard to update reward_items.

Using relationship makes the db schema more complex, and make backend operation on CRUDs operation of reward_items complicated as well.(need to create VirtualItemSet item on the fly etc). It also make query more complicated. But it will support dynamic change of VI.

Whats your opinion on this? Or there is a better database for this type of senario?

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: The 0th law of Codd (to give it a more impressive name than "0th normalization") is (in exactly these words, written on stone tablets back in 1178): "Do not store an array in a column of a relational database if there is any chance you want to modify it, even if user648922 thinks it is easier to read". If you don't want to obey it, don't tag your question with "database-design". Or in short: yes, you should use another table. If the rewards don't change that often, you can implement a cache to save/read them additionally in json format (if you use them in that format in php).

Comment: See the new Tag I added; look at questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you notice: If you use flat column you can't make sql join and keep data consistency by database for foreign keys. In my practice this decision  always make problems in future. So i think better don't use flat columns.